# How do I make sure my android app use vector instead of PNG?

Tags: android

I have been trying to figure it out reading documents and such, I am developing my first app, and I am developing with a minSDK 16, I have encoutered some errors regarding SVG/vectors on older versions that I fixed with PNGs. I have placed those PNGs in different folders as stated in the android developer document (drawable-hdpi, etc). However, I am not sure where to put my SVG/Vector files to make sure phones with SDK 21/24+ use it instead of the PNG.

What is the best practice?

Comment: *I am developing with a minSDK 16* why?

Comment: do you wanna know why am I developing with a minSDK 16? I dont know, it doesnt seem to make difference if it is 16 or 19, or 20 for this case, right?

Comment: Definitely SVGs if you can as it saves effort and reduces apk size. Moreover the appcompat lib supports it almost at every place.

Comment: let me rephrase then. Any reason your minSdk is not 21?

Comment: @amit, I know, but I where do I place them to make sure android with sdk21+ will always use it instead of PNG?

Comment: @TimCastelijns I wanna have my app available to everyone, is a very simple one. I will also have it in portuguese-Brazil, where I believe we still have users with sdk20 or below.

Comment: If you want to use the vector versions only on 21+, you can put them in drawable-v21 with the same name corresponding to png. Android then picks up drawables from this folder for 21 and higher versions.